# Editing a text file in java

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I want add few strings to a text file in a particular location.
I have used `BufferedReader` to read the text file. Then I added the string at the particular position and wrote the modified text to a new temp file using `BufferedWriter`.

Then I deleted the old file and renamed the temp file to old file name.
This works sometimes and does not work sometimes. The `delete()` function sometimes does not delete the file. I have closed all the `BufferedWriter`'s, but the problem still occurs sometimes.

**Code:**

```
public boolean cart(String uname, String item) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("C:\\$$$$.tmp");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    File fileop = new File("C:\\value.text");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileop.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String val[] = line.split(",");
        if (val[0].equals(uname)) {
            String linenew = line + item + "&";
            bw.append(linenew);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
        } else {
            bw.append(line);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
        }
    }
    br.close();
    bw.close();
    fileop.delete();
    file.renameTo(fileop);
    return true;
 }
```

Comment: show ur codes, otherwise debugging will take a millennium !

Comment: can u share what have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry.. I have added the code now..

Comment: put your deletion code in a finally block along with the closing statements

Comment: even after putting the deletion code in finally block.. the problem occurs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself after spending one full day of searching..

Answer is:

It is enough to close the bufferedReader but also the fileReader..

fr.close();   should be inserted after    br.close();